# Will autosys Job run if one of the predecessor job is in terminated state?

Tags: job-scheduling, autosys

Let me know if a JOB A has dependency on JOB B and JOB C (JOB A is scheduled to run on its own time).
JOB C is in successful state and where as JOB C terminated.
Let me know if JOB A will still run or not?

Comment: At the time when JobA is scheduled, it would check for status of dependent jobs. In this case success of both JobB & JobC. Either of then is False, it would skip and check again the next time is it scheduled for.

Comment: So that means it will JOB A will not start since JOB C is in terminated state. Unlike if a predecessor is on ICE, successor still continue to run on its scheduled timing. Is that right?

Comment: Yup, ON_ICE counts like condition is true.